# Entering data into a php form using an ESP32

Tags: php, html, esp32, arduino-ide

I have a simple web server running on a Raspberry Pi connected to my local network. It runs a simple php website that consists of a login page with text entry boxes for a username and password as well as a submit button. The website also has another page that displays some simple information if the login is successful. This part works fine when accessed from another desktop computer connected to my local network.

I have a Sparkfun ESP32 Thing Plus that I would like to use to interact with my website. I am using the Arduino IDE to write my code, as well as the `WiFi.h` library to handle the internet stuff. I am able to connect to my local network, connect to the domain of my local server, and use the following code to request the HTML of the login page of my website:

```
 // This will send the request to the server
  client.print((String)"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + String(host) + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

Is there a way to enter the username and password into the text boxes of the login page, and then "click" the submit button in order to access the second page of my website?

The php form uses a POST method. The PHP form looks like this:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" >Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why do you need to fill the form? Why not simply send a `POST`  request to `login.php`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is technically possible but perhaps not the best approach. Remember that embedded processors are limited in all resources and you should use as less of the program space and memory as possible.

Consider using a different approach where you transmit a username and a password in every call you make to the Pi's webserver, for example:

```
http://login-embed.php?un=abc&pw=123&action=do_this&param=xyz
```

This requires writing a dedicated login page for your Arduino and returning as less information as possible, for instance, it may be enough to return a simple "true" instead of "Operation succeeded with provided parameters".

As for security, it may be enough for what you do now but as http calls are sent as plain text it can be easily sniffed. It does not mean you have to run and add certificates on all nodes, just that you have to plan for that if you intend to deploy a system that transmit sensitive data.